# Unable to update Published var from Class

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a published var `prediction`:

```
class TrainingStatus: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isTrained: Bool = false
    @Published var modelUrl: URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "hello")
    @Published var prediction:String = ""
}
```

I try to update this variable within a class:

```
class ClassificationController: ObservableObject {
...
 func processObservations(for request: VNRequest, error: Error?) {
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let results = request.results as? [VNClassificationObservation] {
          if results.isEmpty {
            print("nothing found")
          } else {
              print("got a result: \(results)!")
              let top3 = results.prefix(3).map { observation in
                String(format: "%@ %.1f%%", observation.identifier, observation.confidence * 100)
              }
              self.prediction = top3.joined(separator: " ")
              
              // attempt to set environment variable?
              let trainingStatus = TrainingStatus()
              trainingStatus.prediction = self.prediction
              
              print("set prediction: \(trainingStatus.prediction)")
          }
}
```

And display this variable in my UIView:

```
struct SidebarView: View {
   
    @EnvironmentObject var trainingStatus: TrainingStatus
 
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            NavigationView{
                    Section{
                        Text("Trained? " + String(trainingStatus.isTrained))
                        Text("Prediction: \(trainingStatus.prediction)")
                    }
                    
                }
                .navigationTitle("Data")
            }
            .environmentObject(modelData)
            .environmentObject(trainingStatus)
        }
    }
}
```

But although it seems like the `prediction` value gets updated in the `ClassificationController`, my UI view with the Text `\(trainingStatus.prediction)` never gets updated.

How can I update my view to grab the latest published value?

Comment: as you found out, you cannot do this: `let trainingStatus = TrainingStatus()
              trainingStatus.prediction = self.prediction`. Read a bit more on how to use ObservableObject and how to pass them around. What you want to achieve is to use only 1 TrainingStatus.

Comment: @workingdog can you suggest any resources for how to correctly set the observable object?

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize what is effectively (almost) a singleton.

You would first need to change your ObservableObject class and add a new constant:

```
     class TrainingStatus: ObservableObject {
        @Published var isTrained: Bool = false
        @Published var modelUrl: URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "hello")
        @Published var prediction:String = ""

        public static let shared = TrainingStatus()
    }
```

Then you could access it elsewhere by declaring the following:

```
var trainingStatus = TrainingStatus.shared
```

Now you can modify its value however you like. This will update it in the ObservableObject class as well, therefore changing it in whatever other views are using it.

Example for your use case:

```
 struct SidebarView: View {
   
    var trainingStatus = TrainingStatus.shared
 
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            NavigationView{
                    Section{
                        Text("Trained? " + String(trainingStatus.isTrained))
                        Text("Prediction: \(trainingStatus.prediction)") //This is now referencing your new shared variable of trainingStatus
                    }
                    
                }
                .navigationTitle("Data")
            }
            .environmentObject(modelData)
            .environmentObject(trainingStatus)
        }
    }
}
```

Class where you want to modify the constant:

```
 class ClassificationController: ObservableObject {
 
 var trainingStatus = TrainingStatus.shared

...
 func processObservations(for request: VNRequest, error: Error?) {
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let results = request.results as? [VNClassificationObservation] {
          if results.isEmpty {
            print("nothing found")
          } else {
              print("got a result: \(results)!")
              let top3 = results.prefix(3).map { observation in
                String(format: "%@ %.1f%%", observation.identifier, observation.confidence * 100)
              }
              self.prediction = top3.joined(separator: " ")
              
              // attempt to set environment variable?
              //let trainingStatus = TrainingStatus() --- no longer need this line
              trainingStatus.prediction = self.prediction //this is now changing your singleton
              
              print("set prediction: \(trainingStatus.prediction)")
          }
}
```

Comment: edited to add examples within the code you provided